# How to complete this Ajax PHP searchbar

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a search bar to find some data based on a person ID number.
I've made it work with just plain PHP, but, now I want to implement an animation when clicking it. I already made it too. The point is, that I need to send the data via Ajax to avoid refreshing the page and the animation can work.

*I didn't include my ajax, since it does not work, and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. The code on the Jquery script launches the animation

Please help me, I'm a newbie with Ajax. Thanks in advance.

**This is my HTML**

```
<head>

    <title>
        Consultapp :: Consultar
    </title>

    <?php include_once('head-attrib.php'); ?>

    <!-- Search Trasition-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {

            var box = $('.card-searchcard');
            var logo = $('.logo-search');
            var copy = $('.copy');
            var button = $('#searchBar button');
            button.one('click', function(){

                box.toggleClass('active');
                logo.toggleClass('active');
                copy.toggleClass('active');

             });

        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="content">

        <section>

            <img src="source/img/logo.png" class="logo logo-small logo-search">

            <p class="copy">Para consultar, ingresa un numero de cedula.</p>

            <div class="card card-searchcard animated">

                <form id="searchBar" method="get">

                    <input type="search" class="field" name="searchBox" id="searchBox" placeholder="Ingresa una identificacion aqui" min="11111111" max="9999999999">

                    <button class="btn btn-main btn-bar right"><span class="text">CONSULTAR</span><i class="material-icons md-36 md-light">search</i></button>

                </form>

            </div>

            <br>

            <?php print($message) ?>

            <?php print($entry) ?>

            <?php include_once('navbar.php'); ?>

        </section>

    </div>

</body>
```

**and this is the PHP script I'm trying to run.**

```
include_once("global.php");

// Collecting input variables
$entry = '';
$message = '';
$search = $_GET['key'];

if(isset($search)) {

    // Validation
    if (empty($search)) {

            $message = "Necesito un numero para consultar";

        }

    else{

        $searchquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submissions WHERE id='$search'") or die("Could not check ID, I'm search");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($searchquery);

        if ($count == 0) {

            $no_results = array( //Funny Error Messages goes here

                '<span>Ups</span><br>Esta persona aun no ha sido calificada<br>Puedes añadir una calificacion si lo deseas',

                '<span>Hay Caramba</span><br>nadie sabe acerca de esta persona<br> Tu sabes? Genial, añade una calificacion.',

                );

            $message = $no_results[array_rand($no_results)];

        }

        else{

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($searchquery)) {

                $name = $row['name'];
                $id = $row['id'];
                $amount = $row['amount'];
                $submitter = $row['submitter'];
                $rating = $row['rating'];

                $entry .= (" $amount $rating $submitter");

                echo ($entry);

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A standard ajax call (using jquery)

```
    var dataString = 'nombre=' + nombre + '&email=' + email + '&mensaje=' + mensaje; // Here you can configure your post data to send
    //alert (dataString);return false; / Uncomment if you want to check what are you trying to send
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myfile.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function( data ) {
            //Do your thing here, and access the response as data like:
            //$("#contenedor-llamada-ajax").html(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: How do I print my php variable in `sucess{}`

Comment: The code in the call `$("#contenedor-llamada-ajax").html(data);` will populate the #contenedor-llamada-ajax div/p/etc with the data collected from the call. According to your code, if the call is successfull, you should get back the `echo ($entry);` for each entry if there is no results, you will get nothing because the `$message` var is local, so you would need to print it to retrieve it with the ajax call.

Comment: Hi, I used the code and it seems to work, but no complete. It collects the data, and send it, I think. But I dont get any response back. Shouldn't I add something to the PHP or so?

Comment: Set the script to echo $message in case of errors or $entry in case of success (this is already done in your script). Then act accordinly in the success call, like `var string = "<span>"; if (data.indexOf(string) > -1) { //do fail stuff, like $("#error-container").html(data); } else { //do success stuff }`